# How can I create a NSPopUpButton that uses a fixed Image, and no arrows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to get `NSPopUpButton` to render like a standard `NSButton` with only an image set, but not having any luck.

Much like the "+" button in Mail.app:

[image: Not clicked]
[image: Clicked]

I assume they did this with `NSPopUpButton`.  The obvious thing I've tried is:

```
NSMenuItem *imageItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] init] autorelease];
[imageItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameAddTemplate]];

[[popUpButton cell] setUsesItemFromMenu:NO];
[[popUpButton cell] setMenuItem:imageItem];
[[popUpButton cell] setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
```

This doesn't show the image however, instead it just shows a pair of arrows (I suspect they're drawn over where the image would be).  Calling `[popUpButton setImage:...]` also does nothing.

Is there a documented way to do this, or does it come down to some custom subclassing?

Answer (score 4):

To prevent the button from displaying the arrow:

```
[popupButton.cell setArrowPosition:NSPopUpNoArrow];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code I used to finally get this working in Swift (modeled after Apple's [Menu Madness](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MenuMadness/Introduction/Intro.html) demo app).

```
func setUpButton() {
    let popupButton = NSPopUpButton()
    popupButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    popupButton.pullsDown = true
    popupButton.bordered = false
    let popupCell = popupButton.cell as! NSPopUpButtonCell
    popupCell.arrowPosition = NSPopUpArrowPosition.NoArrow
    popupButton.addItemWithTitle("")
    var item = popupButton.itemAtIndex(0)
    item?.image = NSImage(named: "add")
    item?.onStateImage = nil
    item?.mixedStateImage = nil
    popupButton.addItemWithTitle("Item1")
    item = popupButton.itemAtIndex(1)
    item?.action = #selector(item1Pressed)
    item?.target = self
    popupButton.addItemWithTitle("Item2")
    item = popupButton.itemAtIndex(2)
    item?.action = #selector(item2Tapped)
    item?.target = self
    self.addSubview(popupButton)

    // NOTE: These are auto layout helper methods I made that you won't have. 
    // Just note that here is where I set up the auto layout constraints.
    popupButton.widthConstraint(40)
    popupButton.heightConstraint(20)
    popupButton.centerVerticallyInSuperview()
    popupButton.trailingSpaceToSuperview(0)
}

// TO MAKE SURE ALL ITEMS ALWAYS VALID (WHAT I WANTED FOR MY USE CASE)
override func validateMenuItem(menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func item1Pressed() {
    // do stuff
}

func item2Pressed() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Be sure to make the width/height of the button big enough for the image. I found there was some padding on the right side of the button that covered my small image until I made the button wide enough to accommodate the mysterious padding.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, yes it is probably implemented with an `NSPopUpButton`, but rather than trying to customize the cell, what you really want is a button with `-pullsDown:` set to `YES`.

This is easiest to set up in Interface Builder. Even easier, use BWToolkit which features a button bar and custom buttons specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I do need `pullsDown`.  What I was actually struggling with however was getting my image to display without displaying the arrows.  The Menu Madness sample Laurent mentions has some great examples for little tricks I need to achieve.  I'm learning a great deal from building this Cocoa app (which has turned into a much bigger task than I first thought).

Answer (score 1):

@Laurent Etiemble's (now deleted) answer helped me and the OP.

> Take a look at [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/79342-popupbutton-with-custom-apparence-using-an-image.html) and the Apple's sample [Menu
>   Madness](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MenuMadness/): they contains some sample code to put an image on a
>   `NSPopUpButton`.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.4 you can do all this by using Interface Builder.

1. drag the standard `NSPopUpButton` to your window,
2. select the Style as whatever type of button you want,
3. chose the button to have an image but don't set the image,
4. drag an `NSImage` of whatever icon you want on top of the button.

I found that using the `NSImage` instead of setting the image of the button worked much better.  Setting the button image caused problems when selecting items in the popup menu.